# request url schema, user info and path name lost in node.js app on heroku

Tags: node.js, http, authentication, heroku, request

I have a node app and am attempting to use url user info to authorize requests.  When I  run my app on heroku, I notice that request.url includes only the path component of the url.  Does anyone know why this happens?  And if there is a way to access the url schema, user info, and  hostname?

Here is a simplified example:

```
httpServer = http.createServer(function(request, response){
  console.log("RECEIVED HTTP REQUEST - " + request.url);
});
```

When I run this locally, and post to `http://username:password@localhost:5000/path`, the full url is logged:

```
10:42:03 web.1  | RECIEVED HTTP REQUEST - http://username:password@localhost:5000/path
```

When I run it on heroku, and post `http://username:password@appname.herokuapp.com/path`,
it logs only the path component:

```
2014-03-25T15:40:49.965899+00:00 app[web.1]: RECEIVED HTTP REQUEST - /path
```